# Count prediction with Poisson Regression

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model

Is it essential to have the data grouped in a Poisson regression? An example:

I want to know the determinants of traffic accidents in a country through data from two cities. My 3 explanatory variables are the number of young people, gender and the number of cars.

Later I want to know if my model correctly predicts the number of accidents in each city.

```r
poisson <- glm(accidents ~ group_age + gender + cars, 
               offset=log(population), family="poisson", data)
```

Must the data organized by this way?

```r
ga <- c("young", "old", "young", "old", "young", "old", "young", "old")
gender <- c("1", "1", "0", "0", "1", "1", "0", "0")
city <- c("a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b")
accidents <- c(10, 20, 30, 40, 20, 30, 20, 1)
population <- c(10, 20, 10, 10, 30, 10, 33, 22)
a <- cbind(ga, gender)
a <- cbind(city, a)
a <- cbind(a, accidents)
a <- cbind(a, population)
a
```

Or must I group_by the information previousle to run GLM?

```r
df <- a%>%
group_by(ga, gender)%>%
summarise(accidents=sum(accidents), population=sum(population))
```

Comment: You haven't explained the data (is this a real or hypothetical example?) and what is your reasoning to aggregate. But in general, I don't see why you would group by ga & gender. You lose the `city` column in the process as well.

Comment: Furthermore, the term "determinant" is rather strong and suggests a causal relationship between the predictors and response. You can't demonstrate causality with a regression analysis on its own. To complicate things, in your case it's not clear how "age" and "gender" describe the (often multiple) people involved in a car accident.